# How do I save changes after editing vi /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, vim, centos, vi

I am doing a Linux installation. I installed the system fine and am trying to change the vi `/etc/hosts` file. I have edited the file but am not sure how to save it.

I have `--INSERT--` showing at the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

First press ESC so you get back to command mode, then do.

```
:x (quit and save)
```

or

```
:w
and
:q
```

or

```
:wq
```

Comment: I believe you can also do `:wq` to save and quit in one command.

Comment: @Grant Palin, That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the shortcut Shift-Z-Z from command mode (as Anders said, press Esc to exit Insert mode and return to Command mode) to save and exit to the command prompt.